# Invalid recursion of an element

Tags: python, recursion

My task is to print depth of an element or print that element is not in the list.

My code:

```
def depthFunction(element, listOfElements, depth = 0, exist =0):
    for item in listOfElements:
        if isinstance (item, str):
            if element == item:
                print("Depth of element " + element + " is "+ str(depth))
            exist = True
            return True
        else:
            exist = depthFunction(item, listOfElements, depth+1) #edited
    
    if depth!=0:
        return exist
    if depth == 0 and not exist:
        print ("Element "+ element +" is not on this list") #changed
        
        
if __name__== '__main__':
    depthFunction('g',['a',['b','c','d'], ['e','f']]) #Not in the list
    depthFunction('e',['a',['b','c','d'], ['e','f']]) #Depth is 2
    depthFunction('a',['a',['b','c','d'], ['e','f']]) #Depth is 0
    depthFunction('d',['a',['b','c','d'], ['e','f']]) #Depth is 1
```

I got only a is 0 with this code.

Comment: For one thing, `"element " + x +" is not on this list"` should be `element` instead of `x`.

Comment: For another, your recursion should be passing `item`, not `listOfElements`.

Comment: Thanks, both mistakes changed.

Comment: But still, code is not working properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to separate the computation from the output: have one function that computes the depth, and a different function that prints out the result. This makes things easier to test and more compatible with recursion.

```py
def depthFunction(element, listOfElements):
    for item in listOfElements:
        if isinstance(item, str):
            if item == element:
                return 0
        else:
            recurse = depthFunction(element, item)
            if recurse is not None:
                return 1 + recurse
    return None


def print_depth(element, listOfElements):
    depth = depthFunction(element, listOfElements)
    if depth is None:
        print(f"Element {element} is not in this list")
    else:
        print(f"Element has depth {depth}.")


print_depth("a", [[[]], ["b", ["a"]]])
# Element has depth 2.
```